# How can I prevent a JSlider from moving full-range?

Tags: java, swing, jslider, changelistener

I have an application where I want to use a `JSlider` for user input, representing a percentage of an absolute value.
 Based on other variables, the minimum/maximum percentage value will be limited. I don't want to change the scale (min/max) of the `JSlider` itself (I want to preserve the full-range percentage scale). I created a `ChangeListener` that determines if the range needs to be limited, and when so, I call the `JSlider.setValue()` method with the appropriate (limited min/max) value. However, the `JSlider` itself does not reflect the value I've set. If I query the value with `JSlider.getValue()` it returns what I would expect (the value I set).

Is there a way to force the `JSlider` to only allow dragging the actual slider (thumb, knob) to a certain point, then stopping?

Update:

After spending too much time on this, I've decided that the root problem is that I'm misusing/abusing the JSlider in an unintended use model. Restricting the range of movement of the thumb to be less than the BoundedRangeModel range requires modification of the BasicSliderUI class. While the original solution proposed by *aterai* below does work, it requires overriding a SliderUI implementation class, impacting the portability and consistency of a plaf. So, either I have to find a different UI element or modify the JSlider BoundedRangeModel limits based on the other interdependent variable values. The downside of the latter is that the same thumb position will represent a different value based on the value of other user-editable parameters.

Comment: You will probably need to provide a custom `BoundedRangeModel`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I believe that is what I have created, in effect. The ChangeListener decides if the value is valid or not, and if not, sets the JSlider value to a "legal" value (which does persist). However, the thumb does not reflect that value, but rather the value where the thumb was moved by the user..

Comment: How about rather than "in effect" you make it actual, after all, it's the `BoundedRangeModel`s responsibility to manage these things, and your current approach doesn't seem to work

Comment: @MadProgrammer with a custom model based on DefaultBoundedRangeModel I was still unsuccessful. Overriding setValue() and intercepting an illegal attempted value and substituting a legal value did  not work. Even when forcing a fireStateChanged() call just to be sure. I can't see the source (working on Mac, Aqua LaF) but symptoms lead me to suspect that the mouse release always sets the thumb position despite the value set in the model.

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to override the `createTrackListener(...)` method of `MetalSliderUI` to prevent that dragging.

[image]

**Edit**

- Another option is to use a `JLayer`(untested code, may take some customization to work for other `LookAndFeel`):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSliderUI;
// import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalSliderUI;
// import javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthSliderUI;
// import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsSliderUI;

public class DragLimitedSliderTest {
  private static int MAXI = 80;
  private JComponent makeUI() {
    JSlider slider1 = makeSlider();
    JSlider slider2 = makeSlider();
    slider2.setUI(new BasicSliderUI(slider2) {
    //slider2.setUI(new WindowsSliderUI(slider2) {
    //slider2.setUI(new MetalSliderUI() {
    //slider2.setUI(new SynthSliderUI(slider2) {
      @Override protected TrackListener createTrackListener(JSlider slider) {
        return new TrackListener() {
          @Override public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            //case HORIZONTAL:
            int halfThumbWidth = thumbRect.width / 2;
            int thumbLeft = e.getX() - offset;
            int maxPos = xPositionForValue(MAXI) - halfThumbWidth;
            if (thumbLeft > maxPos) {
              int x = maxPos + offset;
              MouseEvent me = new MouseEvent(
                e.getComponent(), e.getID(), e.getWhen(), e.getModifiers(),
                x, e.getY(),
                e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen(),
                e.getClickCount(), e.isPopupTrigger(), e.getButton());
              e.consume();
              super.mouseDragged(me);
            } else {
              super.mouseDragged(e);
            }
          }
        };
      }
    });
    JSlider slider3 = makeSlider();

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    p.add(slider1);
    p.add(slider2);
    p.add(new JLayer<JSlider>(slider3, new DisableInputLayerUI()));
    return p;
  }
  private static JSlider makeSlider() {
    JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 100, 40) {
      @Override public void setValue(int n) {
        super.setValue(n);
      }
    };
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);
    Dictionary dictionary = slider.getLabelTable();
    if (dictionary != null) {
      Enumeration elements = dictionary.elements();
      while (elements.hasMoreElements()) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel) elements.nextElement();
        int v = Integer.parseInt(label.getText());
        if (v > MAXI) {
          label.setForeground(Color.RED);
        }
      }
    }
    slider.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
      @Override public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        BoundedRangeModel m = (BoundedRangeModel) e.getSource();
        if (m.getValue() > MAXI) {
          m.setValue(MAXI);
        }
      }
    });
    return slider;
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
//         for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo laf: UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
//           if ("Nimbus".equals(laf.getName())) {
//             UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf.getClassName());
//           }
//         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new DragLimitedSliderTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}

class DisableInputLayerUI extends LayerUI<JSlider> {
  @Override public void installUI(JComponent c) {
    super.installUI(c);
    if (c instanceof JLayer) {
      JLayer jlayer = (JLayer) c;
      jlayer.setLayerEventMask(
        AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK |
        AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK);
    }
  }
  @Override public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {
    if (c instanceof JLayer) {
      JLayer jlayer = (JLayer) c;
      jlayer.setLayerEventMask(0);
    }
    super.uninstallUI(c);
  }
  private Rectangle thumbRect = new Rectangle(11, 19); //magic number
  private Rectangle focusRect = new Rectangle();
  private Rectangle contentRect = new Rectangle();
  private Rectangle trackRect = new Rectangle();
  private int offset;

  protected int xPositionForValue(JSlider slider, int value) {
    int min = slider.getMinimum();
    int max = slider.getMaximum();
    int trackLength = trackRect.width;
    double valueRange = (double) max - (double) min;
    double pixelsPerValue = (double) trackLength / valueRange;
    int trackLeft = trackRect.x;
    int trackRight = trackRect.x + (trackRect.width - 1);
    int xPosition;

    xPosition = trackLeft;
    xPosition += Math.round(pixelsPerValue * ((double) value - min));

    xPosition = Math.max(trackLeft, xPosition);
    xPosition = Math.min(trackRight, xPosition);

    return xPosition;
  }
  protected int getHeightOfTallestLabel(JSlider slider) {
    Dictionary dictionary = slider.getLabelTable();
    int tallest = 0;
    if (dictionary != null) {
      Enumeration keys = dictionary.keys();
      while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
        JComponent label = (JComponent) dictionary.get(keys.nextElement());
        tallest = Math.max(label.getPreferredSize().height, tallest);
      }
    }
    return tallest;
  }
  @Override protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer<? extends JSlider> l) {
    JSlider slider = l.getView();
    if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
      //case HORIZONTAL:

      //recalculateIfInsetsChanged()
      Insets insetCache = slider.getInsets();
      Insets focusInsets = UIManager.getInsets("Slider.focusInsets");
      if (focusInsets == null) {
        focusInsets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2); //magic number
      }

      //calculateFocusRect()
      focusRect.x = insetCache.left;
      focusRect.y = insetCache.top;
      focusRect.width = slider.getWidth() - (insetCache.left + insetCache.right);
      focusRect.height = slider.getHeight() - (insetCache.top + insetCache.bottom);

      //calculateContentRect()
      contentRect.x = focusRect.x + focusInsets.left;
      contentRect.y = focusRect.y + focusInsets.top;
      contentRect.width = focusRect.width - (focusInsets.left + focusInsets.right);
      contentRect.height = focusRect.height - (focusInsets.top + focusInsets.bottom);

      //calculateThumbSize()
      Icon ti = UIManager.getIcon("Slider.horizontalThumbIcon");
      if (ti != null) {
        thumbRect.width = ti.getIconWidth();
        thumbRect.height = ti.getIconHeight();
      }

      //calculateTrackBuffer()
      int trackBuffer = 9; //magic number, Windows: 9, Metal: 10 ...

      //calculateTrackRect()
      int centerSpacing = thumbRect.height;
      if (slider.getPaintTicks())  centerSpacing += 8; //magic number getTickLength();
      if (slider.getPaintLabels()) centerSpacing += getHeightOfTallestLabel(slider);
      trackRect.x = contentRect.x + trackBuffer;
      trackRect.y = contentRect.y + (contentRect.height - centerSpacing - 1) / 2;
      trackRect.width = contentRect.width - (trackBuffer * 2);
      trackRect.height = thumbRect.height;

      //calculateThumbLocation()
      int valuePosition = xPositionForValue(slider, slider.getValue());
      thumbRect.x = valuePosition - (thumbRect.width / 2);
      thumbRect.y = trackRect.y;
      offset = e.getX() - thumbRect.x;
    }
  }
  @Override protected void processMouseMotionEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer<? extends JSlider> l) {
    if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
      JSlider slider = l.getView();
      //case HORIZONTAL:
      int halfThumbWidth = thumbRect.width / 2;
      int thumbLeft = e.getX() - offset;
      int maxPos = xPositionForValue(slider, 80) - halfThumbWidth;
      if (thumbLeft > maxPos) {
        e.consume();
        SliderUI ui = slider.getUI();
        if (ui instanceof BasicSliderUI) {
          ((BasicSliderUI) ui).setThumbLocation(maxPos, thumbRect.y);
        }
        slider.getModel().setValue(80);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue I see with this approach is that I'm now locked into a specific LaF. My application runs on Windows, Mac, Linux. Just trying to test this approach I've run into problems with Eclipse complaining about trying to access a non-public API without permission. Overriding the TrackListener seems to be the way, but that isn't part of a public API that I can find.

Comment: While overriding the TrackListener seems to be a solution, I haven't found a way to use this in practice when the SliderUI implementation class is unknown. I suppose I could determine the class at runtime and if it is one known to me (and not final) override the TrackListener as in your example. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's really no way to do what I wanted in a way that will be consistent across different Look and Feel implementations. Tracing through the notifications and listeners of the JSlider, BasicSliderUI, and BoundedRangeModel it turns out that there is no way to force a recalculation of the thumb position through public methods and the base listener implementation specifically prevents this from happening when dragging or terminating the drag (mouse release). See update to original question for more.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know this is a really old post but there is a method which might not have existed before called "slider.setExtent(int value)" It does exactly what you're looking for. It takes an int value that represents the value that is taken away from the max value of the JSlider. For example if I have a slider that goes from 0-100 and I use "slider.setExtent(20)" then the user will only be able to slide up to the value 80 in the JSlider and it won't let them slide past that. Hope this helps, sorry if this is poorly explained it is my first time answering a question on here.

Here is the link that explains this better, this is where I discovered this:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java-program-to-set-the-extent-in-jslider

Comment: interestingly, this indeed is working and might even suit the asker - the question isn't overly clear, IMO :)